# Converting a png file to a window (owin) file in spatstat

Tags: geospatial, spatstat

I have a png file like this -

[image: png file]

I want to make this as a window of observation ('owin' type) in spatstat. I also have the coordinates of these points, but if I use them directly to create a window using  `Z <- owin(poly=list(x=x-coordinate, y=y-coordinate))`, I get something crazy like this -

[image]

How do I get this as a window? Thanks

Comment: We need more details about your data. Can  you share the data or just parts of it so we can see the structure? Is this a map of a specific region of the world? In that case there may be data readily available in R packages.

Comment: Hi Ege Rubak,
Sure, will be happy to share the data. This is from biology. I am applying spatstat to understand the distribution of cells and their interactions. I would like to do some correspondence. Thanks.

Comment: The usual way to share the data would be by a link to Google Drive, Dropbox, .... We can't really help you in detail without access to the data.

Comment: Hi Ege, thanks. I was able to figure this out. Basically, instead of messing with polygonal boundaries, I converted into a mask and used as.polygonal. This turned out to be very useful and efficient.

Comment: Accuracy will be lost if you convert to a pixel mask and then convert back again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function to convert your coordinate data to a window object (`owin`).

It assumes you have collected all the polygon vertex coordinates into a data frame with columns `x`, `y` and `id`, where `x` and `y` are the coordinates and `id` is an integer which distinguishes each of the curves that you want to treat as separate closed curves.

```
df2owin <- function(df) {
  ## check that 'df' is a data frame with columns x, y, id
  stopifnot(is.data.frame(df))
  stopifnot(ncol(df) == 3)
  stopifnot(all(c("x", "y", "id") %in% colnames(df)))
  ## separate according to 'id'
  z <- split(df[,c("x","y")], factor(df$id))
  ## force all curves to be traversed anticlockwise
  z <- lapply(z, as.list)
  areas <- sapply(z, spatstat.utils::Area.xypolygon)
  neg <- (areas < 0)
  if(any(neg)) z[neg] <- lapply(z[neg], spatstat.utils::reverse.xypolygon)
  ## convert them to individual windows
  winlist <- lapply(z, function(a) owin(poly=as.list(a)))
  ## now figure out which curves fall inside other curves
  n <- length(winlist)
  isinside <- logical(n)
  for(i in 1:n) {
    for(j in (1:n)[-i]) {
      if(is.subset.owin(winlist[[i]], winlist[[j]])) {
        isinside[i] <- TRUE
        break
      }
    }
  }
  ## assume there are no islands-within-holes etc.
  ishole <- isinside
  ## holes should be traversed clockwise
  if(any(ishole)) z[ishole] <- 
      lapply(z[ishole], spatstat.utils::reverse.xypolygon)
  ## now make the combined window
  result <- owin(poly=z)
  return(result)
}
```

Comment: This is great! Can't thank you enough for this. One of the very good things about your effort is the way you have made extremely difficult mathematics (measure theory) very accessible for computer scientists and programmers alike and this solution exemplifies that. This will be very useful if integrated into spatstat for life sciences people like me.

Answer (score 1):

Your picture shows that the window is composed of several islands. You need to tell that to the software, or it will assume the coordinates are all part of the same island, and join them together.

The help for `owin` says that, in this case, you need to use `owin(poly=list(list1, list2, list3, ...))` where `list1` contains only the coordinates for island 1, `list2` contains coordinates for island 2, and so on. Here `list1` has the format `list(x, y)` but contains only the coordinates for island 1. and so on.

Comment: Dear Prof. Baddeley, thanks for your reply. The regions in the big window are actually holes. I tried your solution and now I get an error saying `Error in owin(poly = l1) : Area of the window is negative; check that all polygons were traversed in the right direction`. I am a computational biology faculty working in cancer research and honestly, geospatial analysis is pretty new for me. But I will try my best to resolve this. Thanks.

Comment: Please have a close look at the help file for `owin`. The big window's outer boundary should be given as `list1=list(x,y)` where the `x,y` coordinates are listed in *counterclockwise* order to specify that it is an outer boundary. The holes should be given as `list2=list(x,y)` etc where the `x,y` coordinates are listed in *clockwise* order to specify that they are holes. The islands should again be given as `list(x,y)` with `x,y` in counterclockwise order. Then call `owin(poly=list(list1,list2, ...))`

Comment: Yes, thank you. I found that out. But in general, I found mask to be a better option since dealing with duplicates and orientation was a bit tough. The 'as.polygonal' is a very nice feature, I should say.

Comment: I have posted a code snippet showing how to handle the coordinate data. (Currently this is stuck in a queue for approval. It should show up soon)